# Detecting Common Elements in an Unsorted Array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I found a code which will detect common elements in an unsorted array. The program runs in linear time! But i did not understand the logic of the program. It would be very helpful if some one could explain the logic of the program.

Here is the code:

```
public class DeleteUnsortedDataFromArray {

    public static List<Integer> findDuplicatesArray(int[] sequence){
        int bitarray = 0;

        for(int i=0; i< sequence.length; i++){
            int x = 1;
            x = x << sequence[i];

            if((bitarray & x) != 0){
                System.out.println("Duplicate found in given array: " + sequence[i]);
            } else {
                bitarray = bitarray | x;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] input = {1,1,2,3};
        findDuplicatesArray(input);
    }

}
```

Comment: Is it just me or is this missing a return statement?

Comment: @Jonn I think it's just you. However what it returns is not entirely useful

Comment: @Varun Try it with `[0, 32, 64]` as the input. But yeah, you can find duplicate elements in linear time if the array contains integers bounded by some constant *C*. Just use a bitset of size *C*.

Comment: @NiklasB.Nice catch! If the input array is [0,32,64] the code bombs! Any idea how to tackle this?

Answer (score 2):

What it does is to represent each found value as an 1 in a position of the bits composing an integer (bitarray).

The lines:

```
x = 1;
x = x << sequence[i];
```

Will put a 1 at the position given by the sequence value+1 (<< [is a shift operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)).

For example, if sequence[i] value is four, x will have the binary value: ...010000

The line:

```
(bitarray & x) != 0
```

Uses bit operation AND to check if a position has been already occupied and hence the valued found.

The problem is that this algorithm only works if your values at *sequence* are constrained to be low: Between 0 and 30 as there are 32 bits in an [Java integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) and the value 0 is represented as a 1 at the position 0 of bitarray.

You should consider too what happens when the sequence values are negative.

Comment: I removed my comments. I would just have liked to see at least one answer mentioning that even if *m* is not considered constant, you can still achieve O(n + m) runtime. You can even use a hash table to get linear expected time independent of m

Answer (score 0):

It works only as long as all values in the array belong to [0, number-of-bits-in-int). If of course you can say 'works' about a function that is supposed to return list of duplicates but always returns null.

Answer (score 0):

You can understand the algorithm as using an array of booleans to test whether a value has occured previously in the array or not. Now instead of using an array of booleans, what you are doing is using the bits in an int to represent whether a value has occured previously or not. The code calls this "bitarray".

To set the Ith bit in an int, you use

```
x = (x | (1<< i));
```

Here '|' is the [bitwise or operator.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Logical_disjunction)

And to test whether the Ith bit has been set you check the condition

```
if((x & (1<< i)) != 0){

}
```

here '&' is the [bitwise and operator.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Logical_conjunction)

Moreover, the `algorithm used above will only work if the range of values in the array is between 0 and 31 inclusive.` That's because java ints are represented using 32 bits. However it consumes lesser space than other alternatives like using a HashSet or an explicit array of booleans.

However, `if space is at a premium, and you know that the range of data in the array is small, you can consider using Bitset class` ([link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html)).